# align-items: stretch not working in my code

Tags: css

I am reading about flex box property align-items and its value. One of the value that I am not able to get is 'stretch'. Below is my code snippet:

```css
.container{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.box1{
  background-color: red;
  width:20vw;
  height: 20vh;
}
.box2{
  background-color: blue;
  width:20vw;
}
.box3{
  background-color: green;
  width: 20vw;
  height:30vh
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
</div>
```

Here, I am expecting that all the three boxes must stretch to occupy maximum height i.e. 30vh. But, the output shows that the boxes height remains same. I have tried by specifying height of the container like 100vh or some other value or even replaced container 'height' property to 'min-height' and set its value to 100%, but nothing is working.

Please suggest me an edit in my code so that the 'stretch' value may be demonstrated.

Comment: Remove align-items: stretch;

Comment: Although I have commented out the 'heights' from individual boxes, all the boxes have stretched to 100% of height of the container which is also the case if we don't use align-items: stretch in the code.

Comment: `align-items: stretch` is the default value in FBL, so that property is obsolete in this case. To allow the stretch the boxes need to be allowed to grow with `flex-grow: 1` or `flex: 1`. Because you are using `width` instead of e.g. `min-width` you force the boxes to that width, regardless of grow and/or stretch values...

Answer (score 2):

The property is overriden by the defined height you have on each element and in any case will not make the items the same height unless it's to fill the container.

So remove the heights and make the container 30vh

**In fact `align-items: stretch;` is the default value to it's actually unnecessary to include it in the first place.**

```css
.container {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20vw;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20vw;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
</div>
```